# How to have two constructors with same number of arguments but for different variables in java

Tags: java, constructor

In my case, The class will have two constructors both taking 3 strings as arguments but one of the string variables that is to be initialized in one of the constructors may differ. 
Is it possible to implement the following:

```
class A {
   String x = null;
   String y = null;
   String z = null;
   String a = null;

   A(String x, String y, String z) {
      ....
   }

   A(String a, String y, String z) {
      ....
   }
}
```

Comment: The instance field `a` is something different than the local field `a`.

Comment: `new A("1", "2", "3")` --> which constructor am I calling?

Comment: The static creation methods with sensible names should do you.

Comment: You might really ask yourself, "Under what circumstances does it make sense to have some of these member variables filled in by the constructor, and under what circumstances should only others be filled in, such that some set of variables are not specified?" Null member variables is not really a good idea and very much suggest your code could be cleaner.

Comment: @damo your reputation is "leet" ;)

Comment: What about this question warranted the downvotes?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, but a quick solution is to use static helpers:

```
class A {

  String x, y, z, a;

  /** Constructor. Protected. See static helpers for object creation */
  protected A(String x, String y, String z, String a) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
    this.a = a;
  }

  /** Construct a new A with an x, y, and z */
  public static A fromXYZ(String x, String y, String z) {
    return new A(x, y, z, null);
  }

  /** Construct a new A with an a, y, and z */
  public static A fromAYZ(String a, String y, String z) {
    return new A(a, null, y, z);
  }
}
```

Comment: Might as well make the constructor private

Comment: My habit-- protected for most things internal unless I know I don't need to subclass it.

Comment: OK, I won't discuss tastes ;) However, such a constructor is package accessible

Comment: You're right about the package accessible!

Comment: You don't need to initialize fields to null as that is the default value anyways.

Comment: Fixed. That was just from me copying his code as a base.

Answer (score 9):

> Is it possible to implement the following

No.

Because the compiler has no built-in crystal ball in order to choose the appropriate constructor at compile time.

Please be aware of two points:

- The parameter names in the constructor signature are lost after compilation - they are pure human sugar. So they cannot be use to dispatch between both ctors.
- The parameter names have nothing to do with the field names. That both are *usually* the same is of no concern to the compiler.

Comment: +1 for the correct answer, though it's worth mentioning alternative approaches to the problem, e.g. a builder.

Comment: This isn't entirely correct. The parameter names are not lost after compilation and they remain in the bytecode in their original form unless obfuscation is done. At least if compiled with standard javac.

Comment: @Andy: They are lost unless you compile the code with debug-settings. And then they are not accessible in the same way as - for example - field names. They are only for (optional) debugging. The reflection API is a good indication for this: There is `Method#getParameterTypes()` but no `Method#getParameterNames()` or similar. For the same reason Java will never have something like named parameters without groundshaking refurbishment.

Comment: Are you sure? I've decompiled plenty of java applications. Unless the application is obfuscated, you can get original parameter and variable names. The standard Java reflection library does not give you runtime access to parameter names. However, you can inspect the bytecode of the class at runtime using certain utilities to do so. (Not common or super useful, but possible).

Comment: @Andy: I'm definitely sure. Method and constructor names are only available as debugging symbols. Try `javap` on a simple class which you compiled _without_ debug settings.

Comment: @A.H.: Hmm. It appears I stand corrected! Parameter names are normally elided by javac.

Comment: My code is basically part of a library, and I have to make the constructors public to another application using my library. So for minimum work on the client application i would want two constructors rather than an abstract one.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot do that. You cannot have two constructors with the exact same signature, nor two methods with the exact same signature. Parameter names do not matter.

One solution is to use what is called static factory methods:

```
// in class A
// Parameter names could be "tar", "feathers" and "rope" for what it matters
public static A withXYZ(String x, String y, String z)
{
    final A ret = new A();
    ret.x = x; ret.y = y; ret.z = z;
    return ret;
}
```

In code:

```
final A myA = A.withXYZ(whatever, you, want);
```

Another solution is to use a [builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

See @Andy's answer below for a ready-made solution.

Comment: Pure habit! I always make variables final where they can be. And I restricted myself since I usually make method parameters final as well. It allows me to spot clearly variables which _will_ be modified.

Answer (score 2):

In short: No.

Long answer:
How different are they? If they're very different you might want to consider creating a base class and extend it.

Another option would be to create a StringType enum and pass it with the constructor.

Generally if you have two similar constructors, you need to review your design.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not. If I wrote:

```
A a = new A("foo", "bar", " ");
```

then which constructor would I have called?

Your options are to use a static method, i.e.:

```
public static A withXYZ(String x, String y, String z) 
{
    final A a = new A();
    a.x = x;
    a.y = y;
    a.z = z;
    return a;
}

A myA = A.withXYZ("foo", "bar", " ");
```

Otherwise you could inject the values after construction using a normal setter, i.e.:

```
A a = new A();
a.setX("foo");
a.setY("bar");
a.setZ(" ");
```